# Updating values or creating a new series

Tags: pine-script

This script is developed to generate waves with cumulative volume according to the specified conditions.
On the last bars, there are cases when conditions do not determine which wave is formed up or down. This is accepted as a fact and we agree to wait for the next bars to form.
After new bars determine the direction of the wave, the previous bars should be added as the beginning of this new wave.
It was assumed that the fulfillment of the conditions for the formation of a wave will be stored in one series and corrections will be made when transferring to another series.
Is it possible to fix the written code or make the implementation by another method, for example, through arrays or offset?

I have reworked the script to use arrays.
A few more clarifications on the algorithm.
An time series of "-1", "0" and "1" is built.

"-1" - DOWN  wave
"0" - neutral wave
"1" - UP wave.

Based on this series, an array is created in which all "0" values are replaced by the first non-zero value on the right.
This should work! BUT for some reason it doesn't work.

```
study("Weis Wave Volume VSA", shorttitle="WWV m1_v4 arr")

var wave = array.new_int(0)
//First main condition for up / down wave formation
CondUp1 = close[2] < close[0] and close[1] < close[0] ?  1 : 0
CondDn1 = close[2] > close[0] and close[1] > close[0] ? -1 : 0 
//Second additional condition for up / down wave formation
CondUp2 = open[1] <= close[0] and close[1] < close[0] ?  2 : 0
CondDn2 = open[1] >= close[0] and close[1] > close[0] ? -2 : 0
//Time series for a wave
wavetemp = 0
if CondUp1 != 0 and CondDn1 == 0
    wavetemp := 1 
if CondUp1 == 0 and CondDn1 != 0
    wavetemp := -1
if CondUp1 == 0 and CondDn1 == 0 and CondUp2 != 0 and CondDn2 == 0
    wavetemp := 1
if CondUp1 == 0 and CondDn1 == 0 and CondUp2 == 0 and CondDn2 != 0
    wavetemp := -1
//Array for wave
begin_index = int(na)
if nz(wavetemp[1]) == 0 and  nz(wavetemp[0]) != 0 
    begin_index := max(array.lastindexof(wave, 1), array.lastindexof(wave,-1))
    array.push(wave, wavetemp[0])
    for i = begin_index + 1 to bar_index - 1
        array.set(wave, i, wavetemp[0]) // New value for historic elements 
else 
    array.push(wave, wavetemp[0])

vol = float(na)
vol := bar_index == 0 ? nz(volume) : ( array.get(wave, bar_index - 1) == array.get(wave, bar_index) ? nz(vol[1]) + nz(volume) : nz(volume) )

up = float(na)
up := array.get(wave, bar_index) == 1 ? vol : na

pd = float(na)
pd := array.get(wave, bar_index) == 0 ? vol : na

dn = float(na)
dn := array.get(wave, bar_index) == -1 ? vol : na

plot(up, style=plot.style_columns, color=color.green)
plot(pd, style=plot.style_columns, color=color.black)
plot(dn, style=plot.style_columns, color=color.red)
```

[UPDATE]

Alternative description of the question.

1. There are conditions that create a series `wavetemp` of values "-1", "0" and "1".
2. From the series `wavetemp`, create a new series `wave`according to the rules:

a. if the value of the series `wavetemp` is equal to "-1" or "1", then it is assigned a new series `wave`;

b. if the value of the series `wavetemp` is "0", then wait until the series of the value is equal to "-1" or "1", all the missing element of the new series `wave` is issued on a first non-zero value

[image]

Comment: This script works fine imo. See [screenshot](https://www.tradingview.com/x/x9i08xrs/). It's not clear to me what the problem is.

Comment: @BjornMistiaen , thank you very much for your interest in my problem. I will try to reformulate my question to make it clearer. Please excuse me for using the Google translate.

Comment: No worries. Just make sure to post a comment when you finished changing the question, so that I get notified.

Comment: @BjornMistiaen , see the update of the question, thanks.

Comment: This cannot be done in Pine. You cannot alter historical datapoints of a series. Explained [here](https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#can-i-use-the--operator-to-assign-values-to-past-values-of-a-series). You will be able to create an array that holds the datapoints like in your picture, but you won't be able to plot them on a bar_index in the past.

Comment: @BjornMistiaen, so I'm trying to draw using functions `line.`, but lack the autoscaling line width setting.

Comment: You cannot autoscale line width. You'd have to use `plot` with `style=plot.style_columns`. It's the perfect solution. I dont know why you'd want to use lines for what you're doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to make a working script through the use of offset. From a programming point of view, this is terrible, but I have no other ideas. My idea is that the last bars have a different plot for each individual bar.

```
plot(wave_vol,      style=plot.style_columns, editable=false, color=wave_col,      offset = -3)
plot(wave_vol_end2, style=plot.style_columns, editable=false, color=wave_col_end2, offset = -2, show_last = 1)
plot(wave_vol_end1, style=plot.style_columns, editable=false, color=wave_col_end1, offset = -1, show_last = 1)
plot(wave_vol_end0, style=plot.style_columns, editable=false, color=wave_col_end0, offset =  0, show_last = 1)
```