# Autoscale vertical line width

Tags: pine-script

I am drawing vertical lines using the function `line.set`
Is it possible to autoscale vertical line width so that it is equal to the candlestick width.
Or other drawing possibilities without using `plot`.

[ADDED]

```
study("V_Line")

var bar0 = line.new(na, na, na, na, width=5, extend=extend.none)
var bar1 = line.new(na, na, na, na, width=5, extend=extend.none)
var bar2 = line.new(na, na, na, na, width=5, extend=extend.none)
vol=0.0

vcolor = close[2] < close[0] and close[1] < close[0] ? color.green : (close[2] > close[0] and close[1] > close[0] ? color.red : color.black)
vol := vcolor[1]==vcolor[0]  ?  nz(vol[1]) + nz(volume) : nz(volume)

line.set_xy1(bar0, bar_index, 0)
line.set_xy2(bar0, bar_index, vol)
line.set_color(bar0, vcolor)

line.set_xy1(bar1, bar_index[1], 0)
line.set_xy2(bar1, bar_index[1], vol[1])
line.set_color(bar1, vcolor[1])

line.set_xy1(bar2, bar_index[2], 0)
line.set_xy2(bar2, bar_index[2], vol[2])
line.set_color(bar2, vcolor[2])
```

[image]

Comment: Could you share the code please? Will make it easier to investigate.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
//@version=4
study("V_Line")

vol=0.0

vcolor = close[2] < close[0] and close[1] < close[0] ? color.green : (close[2] > close[0] and close[1] > close[0] ? color.red : color.black)
vol := vcolor[1]==vcolor[0]  ?  nz(vol[1]) + nz(volume) : nz(volume)

plot(vol, color=vcolor, style=plot.style_columns)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your time. I am looking for a solution without using `plot`.

Comment: Why? If you could explain what end result you're trying to accomplish, it might create some insight into  a solution.

Comment: I do not lose hope of finding a competent solution for this task. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65382313/updating-values-or-creating-a-new-series-update-for-array